# JAVA annotaion for cache on access

Tags: java, caching, annotations

are there is some java annotaion that will allow me to ignore code repet such as

```
private ISource source;

public ISource getSource() {
    return source == null ? source = ... : source;
}

private IProduct product;

public IProduct getProduct() {
    return product == null ? product = ... : product;
}

private IFoo foo;

public IFoo getFoo() {
    return foo == null ? foo = ... : foo;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use a memoizing `Supplier`.

Comment: The other thing is: too often people just assume that lazy init of variables is a good thing, as they somehow rate "minor saving of memory" over increased complexity (and robustness problems) due to "uuups, thingy is still null". So side note: maybe you simply make sure that your fields are always non-null.

Comment: The question is how is `ISomeInterface` created. BTW `foo == null ? foo :...` doesn't make since that is just returning `null`. You probably wan't `!= null`

Comment: @AdamGent `return foo == null ? foo = ... : foo;` will return the value of `...` if foo were null

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino... oh I mis-parsed that. My mind dropped the equals for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue would be how you want to create the objects particularly since they appear to be interfaces and how you create those objects is probably fairly custom.

As @OliverCharlesworth mentioned you could use a [memoized supplier](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize(com.google.common.base.Supplier)). With Java 8 lambdas it is rather terse. You then could make a custom annotation on a supplier field and write your own APT plugin ([see Google's auto project for some examples](https://github.com/google/auto))

e.g.

```
@SupplierToGetter
private final Supplier<ISource> source = Suppliers.memoize( -> new Source());
```

Otherwise one option is just to make the supplier fields as public and not bother generating a getter:

```
public final Supplier<ISource> source = Suppliers.memoize( -> new Source());
```

BTW the memoize will be thread safe unlike `foo == null ? foo = ...`.

**EDIT after comment:**

The Java 7 version would be (using Guava):

```
public final Supplier<ISource> source = Suppliers.memoize( new Supplier<ISource>() { 
    public ISource get() { return new Source(); }
});
```

Comment: there is no solution in java 7?

Comment: There is just use Guava and use an anonymous class instead of a lambda.